# Select2 field not rendering inside partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On a main page for example the Edit.cshtml I have this code here which renders a select 2 with the country flags and it works fine, but when I attempt to move it into a partial view it does not work.

My Html Field which is inside PleasureCraftEditViewPartial.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MooringCountry)
    <select asp-for="MooringCountry" class="form-control select2" style="height:35px" id="MooringCountry" name="MooringCountry">
        <option>Please select Mooring Country</option>
    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="MooringCountry" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The above is in my  PleasureCraftEditViewPartial.cshtml

```
@if (@Model.VesselCat == (int)VesselCat.VesselCatType.Commercial) {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ComercialEditViewPartial")
}

@if (@Model.VesselCat == (int)VesselCat.VesselCatType.MotorBoats || 
     @Model.VesselCat == (int)VesselCat.VesselCatType.SailingBoats || 
     @Model.VesselCat == (int)VesselCat.VesselCatType.SmallBoats) {
   @await  Html.PartialAsync("PleasureCraftEditViewPartial")
}
```

The below is in my Edit.cshtml

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        //Initialize Select2 Elements
        $('.select2').select2();
        var isoCountries = [
            { id: 1, flag: 'gbp', text: 'United Kingdom' },
            { id: 2, flag: 'usa', text: 'United States' }
        ];

        function formatCountry(country) {
            if (!country.id) { return country.text; }
            var $country = $('<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-' + country.flag + ' flag-icon-squared"></span>' + '<span class="flag-text">' + country.text + "</span>");
            return $country;
        };

        //Assuming you have a select element with name country
        // e.g. <select name="name"></select>
        $("[id='Flag']").select2({
            placeholder: "Please Select a Flag",
            templateResult: formatCountry,
            data: isoCountries
        });

        $("[id='MooringCountry']").select2({
            placeholder: "Please Select a Mooring Country",
            templateResult: formatCountry,
            data: isoCountries
        });

        $('#Flag').trigger('change');
    });
</script>
```

There are no errors in my console

[image]

Just an empty dropdown

[image]

Comment: Have you checked for javascript errors in the console? Something looks fishy here, I don't see a closing bracket for `isoCountries`...

Comment: @asawyer sorry thats my indentation just

Comment: @asawyer fixed above but yes no console errors

Comment: At this point I'd set a break point at the `$('.select2').select2();` line and make sure that the control exists as expected. I'd also want to make sure that the partial view is in fact rendering, a break point in the razor sections could help making sure there.

Comment: Its rendering as it wouldnt be visible if its not rendering

Comment: Anther thing you could try is revert back to the working version and compare/contrast the generated html for differences that could be causing the problem.